# Array.push() overwrites previous input in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

Every time when i am pushing something on my array the previous results are replaced with new one. `this.digital` is array where i am pushing the results from loop

```
mounted: function() {
for(let i = 0; i<this.order.items.length; i++){
let productId = Number(this.order.items[i].product);

            for(let j = 0; j < this.products.length; j++){

                if(productId === this.products[j].id){

                    let renderProduct = {};
                    renderProduct = Object.assign(this.products[j], this.order.items[i]);

                    if(renderProduct.delivery_type === 'Digital'){
                        this.digital.push(renderProduct);

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    },
```

I have tried with map and concat but the values are still overwritten:

```
mounted: function() {

for(let i = 0; i<this.order.items.length; i++){
            let productId = Number(this.order.items[i].product);

            for(let j = 0; j < this.products.length; j++){

                if(productId === this.products[j].id){

                    let renderProduct = Object.assign(this.products[j], this.order.items[i]);

                    if(renderProduct.delivery_type === 'Digital'){

                        this.digital = this.digital.concat(renderProduct);

                    }

                }

        }
    }
},
```

Comment: why not use `.map` instead ?

Comment: The problem is either somewhere else in the code we don't have, that affects the array, or `renderProduct` does not get the value you expect it to take... (`console.log` it)

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Where is this.digital defined? Where are all the places that you modify it?
 Are you sure you're not setting it null or some other unintended overwrite before you get to this loop? Because I'm reasonably sure that you are (or maybe after it). As others have said, console.log() it.

Comment: this.digital is reactive data: this.digital = []; 

Then i am trying to fill the array with results but each result overwrites the previous one

Comment: Show your code. This loop isn't overwriting your data. You are somewhere else.

Comment: I ve just placed my whole vue component into jsfiddle. Hope this will help 

URL : https://jsfiddle.net/zygw7t5n/

Comment: Array.push() appends values to an array, it does not remove or alter already existing values in any way. Something else is affecting that piece of code. I suggest you use the dev tools to debug your code.

Comment: console is clear. Let me explain this better. I ve got two order.items.product === 2. each of them contains different keys like email or pice. Them i am merging those values with object from the database this.products ,and trying to push to empty array. If the order.items.product has different value then previous loop works properly and you can see different data.